# Slide div up when scrolling down page to reveal content behind it

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I'm seeking to achieve the effect on the site http://icscreative.com/#home. When you scroll up to the top of the site a div with a background image appears and covers the entire screen. Then when you scroll down, it lifts up, revealing content behind it which does not scroll its way up, but simply resides behind it.

I'm having trouble understanding how this is achieved. So far I have created a div with a relative position named .mainContent which contains my content, a couple paragraphs. I have placed a div inside of that with an absolute position named .slide which has a background image and top and left 0 so as to have it cover the entirety of the .mainContent div.

I imagine jQuery is being used, but I'm not sure how. My initial thought was parallax, but at the same time I don't want text to scroll up from the bottom of the screen, I want it to stay in place behind the .slide div. Is this purely CSS?

Thanks in advance.

Raheel K.

Edit: Here's what I have so far. The #blogHeader does display over the #blog, but when scrolling down both divs move together and the one stays over top of the other. Also, I changed the names of the selectors.

HTML

```
<div id="blog">

<div id="blogHeader"></div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus lacinia ultrices commodo.   Pellentesque dictum consequat nulla, quis elementum ante ornare vel. Nunc non lacus eget diam rutrum tincidunt. Suspendisse vel turpis est. Nulla sit amet libero tellus. Etiam consequat quam rhoncus mauris cursus porta. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam sollicitudin aliquet enim nec blandit. Vivamus faucibus, justo mattis euismod porttitor, metus tellus pulvinar velit, ac rutrum urna lorem id magna. Vestibulum diam lectus, pharetra nec pulvinar a, imperdiet at magna. Ut a pellentesque elit.</p>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#blogHeader{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height: 700px;
    background:url(media/images/image.jpg) no-repeat fixed 50% 50%; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 1;
}

#blog{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Edit 2: Posting jsFiddle to give a better idea of what I'm trying to do and the problem I'm having. http://jsfiddle.net/rHg9d/

Comment: Just so you know scrolling on that site is extremely laggy for me. Maybe you need to optimize it some.

Answer (score 0):

You want to adjust the z-index of each part. If you "inspect element" on their site, you'll notice they have a div with a classname "curtains". Each "curtain" is a different part that you scroll through. You'll also notice the picture of the blimp in the background has a z-index of 1 and everything that scrolls off the page has a z-index of 3, which means they're "on top" of the blimp div.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index

I can post an example if that's not clear.

Comment: I do understand z-index, but if you could post an example it'd be greatly appreciated. Also, please see my edit to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

That effect is sometimes called "parallax". It's actually very simple and can be done with CSS alone, although JS will enhance it. The basic idea is to set a background image on a div and set its position to `fixed`.

```
background: url(img.jpg) no-repeat fixed 50% 50%;
```

Here's a simple demo: http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/parrallax2.htm

In the case of the site you linked to, though, they are not using this method, but a pure JS method. From a quick glance, they might be using Scrollax: https://github.com/karlbright/scrollax

Comment: Ralph, I used the method you suggested and it works well, but I also need the div to move while the one behind it stays in place. Please see my edit in the original post.

Comment: Could you perhaps post a jsFiddle of what you have so far? And perhaps describe in more detail what you want, as I don't have a clear picture of it right now.

Comment: Here's the jsFiddle. I need the div with the background image to move when scrolling down to reveal the content of the div behind it. http://jsfiddle.net/rHg9d/

Comment: I'm still not really clear on what you want to see, but perhaps try removing `position: absolute` on `#blogHeader` and see if that's the effect you want.